# Referencing parent id in d3 after data()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var mini_timelines = this.e.append('g').attr('class', 'mini_timelines');

mini_timelines.selectAll('g')
    .data(Data.transcripts.responses)
    .enter()
    .append('g')j.attr('class', 'timeline')
    .attr('id', function(d, i){ return "tl-" + i})
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d, i){
        return d.filteredText.split(' ');
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect').attr('class', 'timeline-word')
    .attr('id', function(d, i){ return "tl-word-" + i;})
    .text(function(d, i){ return 'hello'});
```

Hi, In this block, I'm trying to create many groups, and inside those groups to great rectangles for each word in a string of text that is stored in `Data.transcripts.responses`. In the snipped above, as you can see the `data()` returns an array of words from the parent array, and then we `enter()` in order to create rectangles for each word. For each rectangle that I create, I'm trying to reference the **parent** id in the `.attr('id', function(d, i){ return "tl-word-" + i;})` line. So instead of `"tl-word-" + i`, I would like to have something like `"tl-" + parent_id + "-word-" + i`, where `parent_id` refers to the index of the parent element.

Does that make sense?

It seems that it should be something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: As per comment by Lars, one can read parent object's ID using `d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('id')` as well.

You cannot access the `data` for the parent element directly in an accessor function in `d3`.

The way to solve it would be to introduce in the `data` for the children a field which contains the `parent_id`. For your data structure, it would involve something like this:

```js
Data.transcripts.responses.forEach(function (childArray, parent_idx) {
    childArray.forEach(function (d) { d.parent_id = parent_idx; });
});
```

Then using it while setting the `id` of the children: `.attr('id', function (d, i) { return 'tl-' + d.parent_id + '-word-' + i; })`.

Comment: You can also do `d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id")`. I don't really see any problem with accessing the parent node as such, although it may indicate that your data model should be revised.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Indeed, I had overlooked that. I still have jQuery lint in my hair. :) I have updated the answer to include your solution.

Comment: In that case, i'm guessing I need to make sure my id in the parent is simply `i` rather than `"tl-" + i`?

Comment: @Genu you cannot have just `i` as the `#id`, it is not allowed. With @LarsKotthoff's method, you'll still need to extract the `index` before you could work with it.